# Given the page id, check if it has children

Tags: child-pages, pages

I need to list subpages, given the id of parent one. I tried as follows:

```
if ($children = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID)) && !empty($children)) {
    //Do stuff here
}
```

But this returns false anyways.

I tried as well `get_page_children($post->ID, array)`, but I think I didn't really get how this function works.

So, is it possible at all to get one page's children? Thank you.

Comment: I think you have a problem in your if-sentence, I don't think you can assign a value to the $children variable and check if it's non-empty within the same if-condition. Try to move the variable assigning part out of it. Test e.g. this code: `if( $x = 1 && ! empty( $x ) ) { echo 'passed';}` and check if you get `passed' output.

Comment: There's also the [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) if you need to *list* subpages of a given page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example from the WP codex for [`get_page_children`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children) does what you are looking for with a page titled "Portfolio":

```
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => '-1'));

// Get the page as an Object
$portfolio =  get_page_by_title('Portfolio');

// Filter through all pages and find Portfolio's children
$portfolio_children = get_page_children( $portfolio->ID, $all_wp_pages );
```

The first part initializes a new WP_Query, then using this is it is querying all pages and returning them as objects set to the `$all_wp_pages` variable.

`get_page_children` needs two arguments: the ID of the parent page, and the list of pages' objects in which to look for that page's children (the `$all_wp_pages` variable above).

For your example to work, you need that list of objects created by the query (`$all_wp_pages`) as the `get_page_children` **doesn't query the DB, but rather checks against that list**.

So, `get_page_children($post->ID, $all_wp_pages)`

In full:

```
$page_id = $post->ID;
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();

$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => '-1'));

$the_pages_children = get_page_children( $page_id, $all_wp_pages );
```

Comment: Still returning empty...

Comment: what is returning empty? have you checked the value of `$all_wp_pages` just before calling `get_page_children()`? Checked `$page_id`? Either of those off?

Comment: $all_wp_pages returns the full list of posts of page type; $page_id is correct, but get_page_children is returning as empty array

Comment: that would be saying there are no children for the page id... the function itself is pretty straightforward, not sure how it could *break*... not saying it couldn't, just don't know why if the `id` has children it would say they don't.       you can see it here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L4354

Comment: Somehow it seems i was getting post_type's id instead of post id itself. I managed to get my var as needed, but maybe i was trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: This seems like a horrible way to do it - read all pages into memory (could be thousands) then filter in php. The logical route is to include the condition in the query surely?

Comment: @steve I was correcting the misunderstanding of how `get_page_children()` worked from the OPs example/question. Though to your point, something like `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_parent' => $id_of_parent ) );` may very well be more efficient. `get_page_children()` goes back to WP1.5 I think... may predate the more versatile `get_post()` that WP_Query uses.

Comment: Sure, i understand that, and its a valid answer. Unfortunately my experinace working with junior php devs (and following the php tag on SO) is that stuff on here gets copy pasted all over the place, so an edit providing the optimal solution, or at least a note that a better solution exists, would be a great service to future visitors